# creating resource in 2 steps in azure with bicep - sparkpool (azure synapse)

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-bicep

I am trying to deploy sparkpool (Microsoft.Synapse.workspaces/bigDataPools@2021-03-01)
with the **libraryRequirements** section **via bicep**.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.synapse/workspaces/bigdatapools?pivots=deployment-language-bicep

```
libraryRequirements: {
  content: 'string'
  filename: 'string'
}
```

My problem is - azurecli returns error that:

> Synapse Spark pool must be created before libraries are installed.

So I get that because of some Azure limitation, I would need to have 2 steps and add the libs in the second one.
I am more familiar with terraform than azure, so i tried with dependsOn, which also exists in bicep

pseudocode:

```
resource sparkpool 'Microsoft.Synapse.workspaces/bigDataPools@2021-03-01'{
}

resource sparkpoolchild 'Microsoft.Synapse.workspaces/bigDataPools@2021-03-01'{
  dependsOn: [
    sparkpool
  ]
  libraryRequirements: {
    content: 'string'
    filename: 'string'
}
}
```

I was hoping that I would be able to add this libs to existing sparkpool resource.
But no luck here, somehow this is not allowed by azure.
Any ideas how to tackle this issue?

Comment: if you wanna reference existing resource, you need to use the `existing` keyword: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/existing-resource

Comment: when you create resource, you need a name and a location. You probably should look at some general documentation about bicep: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/